# Displaying the Time in AM/PM format in android

Tags: android

I am getting the time using a time picker and displaying the time in the text view using following code...

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Toast.makeText(SendMail.this, "Your Appointment time is "+hourOfDay+":"+minute,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TextView datehid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timehidden);
        datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)));
    }
};
```

Now, the issue is when i set the time as 8:00 pm then i get the time displayed as 20:0... I want to display the time as 8:00 pm... How can i do that???

Comment: Lots of people have answered your questions, you just don't respond, don't mark as answered.  It leaves little motivation to help you out.

Comment: Also, a lot of your questions ARE in fact answered, but then you go on to ask MORE questions in the comments, and still leave the question as unanswered.  You should mark them as answered, and then ask a new question.

Comment: I am still a newbie to Stack Overflow. From now on i'll take ur suggestions and do it accordingly.. Thanks for your valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have done like this to achieve it.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        TextView datehid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timehidden);
        if(hourOfDay>12) {
            datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay-12)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
        } else if(hourOfDay==12) {
            datehid.setText("12"+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
        } else if(hourOfDay<12) {
            if(hourOfDay!=0) {
                datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + (String.valueOf(minute) + "am"));
            } else {
                datehid.setText("12" + ":" + (String.valueOf(minute) + "am"));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 47):

```
private String getReminingTime() {
    String delegate = "hh:mm aaa";
    return (String) DateFormat.format(delegate,Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

Comment: Does it give `Am/PM` as well? Seems it wont

Comment: Yes it gives the am pm as well . Thanks @arlen

Comment: In kotlin you will do this:
val currentTime = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
Note: a in there refers to am/pm

Answer (score 9):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
String  currentTime = df.format(currnetDateTime.getTime());
```

Comment: For anyone who might be guessing what is `currnetDateTime` in Pravin's code just like I was ;)  , It is `Calendar currnetDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();` and then `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");


String  currentTime = df.format(currnetDateTime.getTime());`

Answer (score 8):

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
if(now.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM){
   // AM
   System.out.println(""+now.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":AM");
}else{
   // PM
   System.out.println(""+now.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":PM");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it saved much of my time!

Answer (score 4):

```
int am_pm=mycalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
String amOrpm=((am_pm==Calendar.AM)?"am":"pm");
```

But as per my opinion simpleDateFormat would be the best use, like this:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
format.setTimeZone(c.getTimeZone());
String myFormatted time = format.format(c.getTime());
```

It's better as the calendar by default will return 00 for 12 pm, which you might don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I have done like this to achieve it.

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        update_From_Time();
    }
};

DateFormat frmTime=DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
protected void update_From_Time() {
    s = frmTime.format(myCalendar.getTime());
    btnFromTime.setText(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String am_pm = "";

    Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
    datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        am_pm = "AM";
    else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
        am_pm = "PM";

    String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR)+""; 

    ((Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnEventStartTime)).setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be setting alert dialog of two char sequence "AM" and "PM".
below is an example.

```
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {

        CharSequence [] sequences = {
                "AM",
                "PM"
        };
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
        alert.setItems(sequences, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which ==0){
                    if (minute ==0){
                        time.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute+"0"+"AM");
                    }else {
                        time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute+"AM");
                    }
                }else{
                    if (minute ==0){
                        time.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute+"0"+"PM");
                    }else {
                        time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute+"PM");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
```

Hope this help anyone!