# Anyway of getting am/pm from time?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying the Time in AM/PM format in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605470/displaying-the-time-in-am-pm-format-in-android)

I can get the time and turn it into string using:

```
public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "h:mm a";
       SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);

String getstring = dateTimeFormat.format(when.gettime();
```

but how do i get am/pm from it and turn it into string beccause i need it?

Answer (score 20):

try this

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int a = now.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
if(a == Calendar.AM)
   System.out.println("AM"+now.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
 new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()

{

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
TextView datehid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timehidden);
if(hourOfDay>12)
{

    datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay-12)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
}
if(hourOfDay==12)
{
    datehid.setText("12"+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
}
if(hourOfDay<12)
{
    datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"am"));
}
}
};
```

Found on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605470/displaying-the-time-in-am-pm-format-in-android).

Comment: No offence, but this is too hectic method, and kind of overcoding.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it looks like you're using Date objects.  I recommend using Calendar objects instead, if possible.  When needed, you can get a Date object from a Calendar object via Calendar's `getTime()` method.

If you have a Calendar object, you can do the following:

```
Calendar cal = ...;
String ampm = DateUtils.getAMPMString(cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
```

`DateUtils` is part of the Android framework and is available back to API level 3.  `getAMPMString()` returns a localized version of AM/PM.  See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) on the Android developer's site.

If you don't have a Calendar object available you can create one from the date object:

```
Date date = ...;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

However, since Calendar's are on the heavy side, you're better off working with Calendar objects directly instead of creating and trashing them.