# How can I show pm only in my digital clock

Tags: android

I am making an application like there are two digital clock in my app, so one is showing current time and other is showing ISHA PARYER TIME (PRAYER NAME IN ISLAM) and this digital clock will set only the in `hh:mm:ss` and it will not be working like normal clock. It will be displaying only the time but its showing time in `am` and I want to show it only in `pm` Please help me out.

Heres the code :

```
    mCalendar.set(0, 0, 0, hr, min, second);
```

and when I implemented this

```
    mCalendar.set(mCalendar.AM_PM, mCalendar.PM);
```

it implemented the hour to about +3

Comment: please share the code

Comment: Please check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605470/displaying-the-time-in-am-pm-format-in-android

Answer (score 1):

May be you will get the idea of what you want to do. In this code I am showing time in 12 hour format just like AM & PM.

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
 new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()

{

 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
 TextView datehid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timehidden);
if(hourOfDay>12)
{

    datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay-12)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
}
if(hourOfDay==12)
{
    datehid.setText("12"+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"pm"));
}
if(hourOfDay<12)
{
    datehid.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+ ":"+(String.valueOf(minute)+"am"));
}
 }
 };
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks for your response but still I dont get it

Answer (score 0):

THANKS ALL OF YOU BUT I GOT IT :) AND HERE IT IS

```
    mCalendar.set(0, 0, 0, hr, min, second);
        if (mCalendar.get(mCalendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM) {
            mCalendar.set(mCalendar.AM_PM, mCalendar.PM);
        }
```