# Intent extras null on configuration change

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, bundle, extras

I created a layout that displays on a `SurfaceView` and I can get the `setDataSource` by using `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras()`.

Everything works fine until I try to set the landscape layout from `land\layout.xml`.

My logcat is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
at asia.sumikawa.cybereyeview.liveActivity.onCreate(liveActivity.java:65)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4216) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:178) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

My java coding

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_alternate);
//loadLibrary();
final String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extras == null) {
    newString = null;
  } else {
    newString = extras.getString("urlAddress");
  }
} else {
  newString = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("urlAddress");
}
urlLink = "rtsp://" + newString.trim().substring(2);
urlString = newString;
```

The null pointer exception is on line

`urlLink = "rtsp://" + newString.trim().substring(2);`

which gets the value from

`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();`

**PS** I would prefer not using `android:configChanges="orientation"` as I'm trying to make the layout have different height/width value

**EDIT**

After adding these code thanks to **cricket_007**

```
if (newString != null){
  urlLink = "rtsp://" + newString.trim().substring(2);
}else{
  Log.i(LOG,"Error");
}
```

I got this error instead

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference
at asia.sumikawa.cybereyeview.liveActivity.playAll(liveActivity.java:307)
at asia.sumikawa.cybereyeview.liveActivity.onCreate(liveActivity.java:77)
```

which point to these lines of codes

```
void playAll(){
if(urlString.charAt(0) == '1'){
  videoPlay();
}else if(urlString.charAt(0) == '2'){
  videoPlay();videoPlay2();
}else if(urlString.charAt(0) == '3'){
  videoPlay();videoPlay2();
  videoPlay3();
}else if(urlString.charAt(0) == '4'){
  videoPlay();videoPlay2();
  videoPlay3();videoPlay4();
}}
```

Just in case this is needed,these are the codes I use to pass the `String` from the previous class

```
Intent i = new Intent(addressActivity.this, liveActivity.class);
String strName = content.toString();
i.putExtra("urlAddress", strName);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Please try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which gets the value from
>
> ```
> Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
> ```

Not always - if `savedInstanceState` is not null, then `newString` is the value of `savedInstanceState.getSerializable("urlAddress");`, which could possibly return null.

Alternatively, `getIntent().getExtras()` is null, therefore you hit

```
if (extras == null) {
    newString = null;
}
```

Which will definitely cause an error.

In either case, you can catch the error by using this

```
if (newString != null) {
    urlString = "rtsp://" + newString.trim().substring(2);
    // Code that requires urlString
    playAll();
} else {
    // Show an error
}
```

And, then to address the problem, you might have to implement `onSaveInstanceState` to put the url string into that `savedInstanceState` Bundle. But, you should be using `putString` and `getString`, probably, instead of `put` / `get` - `Serializable`. That way you avoid the cast.

In order to find where the variable is getting null, it's just a matter of logging and debugging appropriately.

Approaches to saving your data between orientation changes can be found at [**Handling Runtime Changes**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply,I tried changing `newString = null;` to `newString = "";` I still get the same error.I have updated my question

Comment: @FayZan See my update. Take note of the comment that says `// Code that requires urlString`

Comment: Thanks,I didn't understand what that meant until you added `playAll()`.Will update my progress with you

Answer (score -1):

So I decided to make it manually

I use

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_alternate_land);

} else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_alternate);
}
```

with this setting on `AndroidManifest.xml`

`android:configChanges="orientation"`

This will make the height/width value different without destroying the activity

Comment: The XML content view automatically switches. How does that fix the NullPointerException in the Bundle?

Comment: @cricket_007 I input this command `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` into my AndroidManifest.xml so it wouldn't crash upon orientation.Plus when using `android:configChanges="orientation"` my activity won't be destroyed when it goes landscape which may explains why my `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` is null in the first place.If I remember correctly Bundle extra is temporary,so upon destroy it becomes empty

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not really 100% sure that's the reason though since I'm having similar problem with another code which I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605470/displaying-the-time-in-am-pm-format-in-android

Comment: That link isn't to a question that you posted

Comment: @cricket_007 Oopps,I'm sorry about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38763116/dynamic-time-display-crash-on-orientation/38779986#38779986.I already got it fixed though if you have a better way I'd glad to try it